# How to join two list in prolog without changing variable name

Tags: prolog

This is my sample code

```
append( [], X, X).                                  
append( [X | Y], Z, [X | W]) :-
  append( Y, Z, W).   


test(X,DIST):- 
  append(X,DIST,DIST),
  write(DIST).
```

I call this program using:

```
test([0,1],[1,2,3]).
```

But i just get `false` output. Because I named both variable DIST in the append() call.

Comment: Why are you trying to do it without changing the variable name?

Comment: To expand on what @peter.cyc wrote: your test evaluates `append([0,1], [1,2,3], [1,2,3])` but that is supposed to be false if `append/3` is supposed to work as they described. Perhaps you had something else in mind but then you would need to explain what the relation `append/3` means.

Answer (score 1):

The append/3 predicate reads as follows:
append(X, Y, Z) : Z is the result of appending X to Y.

So, append(X,Y,Y) is read as Y is the result of appending X to Y, which is true only when X is []. E.g. append([], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]) is true.

In all other cases, appending anything a non empty list to Y will not result in the list Y, i.e. it is false. E.g. append([0], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]) is false.

Variables in Prolog are non-mutable: they can be assigned once only, until the system backtracks to before when the assignment is done.

Comment: Just a typo: when X is `[]` (nil in lisp, not null)